# Function inside Function retain cycle

Tags: ios, swift, weak-references, retain-cycle, weak

I was wondering how to avoid retain cycle in the following scenario:

```
private func setupDismissCallbacks() {

  // inner func     
  func dismiss() {
     self.videoExporter?.cancel()
     self.rootViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     self.delegate?.childCoordinatorDidFinish(self)
  }

  // first clousre       
  saveModalViewController.onButtonDismiss = {  [weak self] in
     // not really using `self` here
     guard let self = self else { return }
     dismiss()
  }

  // second clousre  
  saveModalViewController.onDimmedAreaDismiss = { [weak self] in
     // not really using `self` here
     guard let self = self else { return }
     dismiss()
  }

}
```

I have a function `setupDismissCallbacks` that listens to two callbacks from a `saveModalViewController` self property. `dismiss()` is an inner function inside `setupDismissCallbacks` that I'm using to access `self` values.

But inside the closures `onButtonDismiss` and `onDimmedAreaDismiss` I don't access self to call `dismiss`, and I can't add `[weak self]` into `dismiss` function because it's a function.

How can I verify that the calls inside `dismiss` won't cause retain cycle?

Comment: "I don't access self to call `dismiss`" How do you think the `dismiss()` call knows which instance to operate on? I.e. when it's called, what will its value of `self` be?

Comment: @Alexander It's not a class function, calling `self.dismiss()` results in `Value of type 'SaveCoordinator' has no member 'dismiss'`

Comment: @Alexander It's inside the function

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that. Your inner function captures self. Your two closures capture that inner function (including the context it encloses over, which includes `self`). Since your two closures are strongly referenced by `saveModalViewController` (which I assume is strongly referenced by `self`), you have a retain cycle.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid it? I'm trying to reduce repetitive code. One idea is simply to place dismiss() out and place it in the class-scope, but there are a few dismiss options the class could have, so keeping it inside the function keeps it in context, due creates retain cycle

Comment: @Alexander commented above

Comment: Store your code in a closure rather than a local function, and use an explicit capture list to capture self weakly. Then assign that closure to both of those properties, rather than pointlessly wrapping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign your closure to a local variable. At that point, extracting out `dismiss` is pointless, so just inline it:

```
private func setupDismissCallbacks() {     
    let dismissCallback: () -> Void = {  [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.videoExporter?.cancel()
        self.rootViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.delegate?.childCoordinatorDidFinish(self)
    }

    saveModalViewController.onButtonDismiss = dismissCallback
    saveModalViewController.onDimmedAreaDismiss = dismissCallback
}
```

Comment: Why double = = and the space I the middle.

Comment: @kjoe It was a typo

Comment: Looks accurate @Alexander - thanks! Exactly what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander explained the issue in the comments:

> Your inner function captures `self`. Your two closures capture that
>   inner function (including the context it encloses over, which includes
>   `self`). Since your two closures are strongly referenced by
>   `saveModalViewController` (which I assume is strongly referenced by
>   `self`), you have a retain cycle.

You can break this cycle by not having `dismiss` capture `self`.  Pass the `SaveCoordinator` to `dismiss`:

```
private func setupDismissCallbacks() {     
  func dismiss(_ coordinator: SaveCoordinator) {
     coordinator.videoExporter?.cancel()
     coordinator(animated: true, completion: nil)
     coordinator.delegate?.childCoordinatorDidFinish(coordinator)
  }

  // first clousre       
  saveModalViewController.onButtonDismiss = {  [weak self] in
     guard let self = self else { return }
     dismiss(self)
  }

  // second clousre  
  saveModalViewController.onDimmedAreaDismiss = { [weak self] in
     guard let self = self else { return }
     dismiss(self)
  }

}
```

Comment: DRY. Just extract out that repeated closure to a variable, and assign it twice.

Comment: Also thought about that - Thank you for the answer - seems like it's scenario dependent, but Alexander solution suits more to this one. Thank you again!